# Dynamically adding ID to element within one of many forms on a page

Tags: jquery

I apologize if my title is a bit confusing. I couldn't think of a good way to title it.

Anyways, I'm looking for some help with some jQuery.

I have a page, that has 3 forms. All the form fields in each form get pre-populated with values and are disabled by default.

Each form has an "edit" link (all have the same class attached), that once clicked will remove the disabled property, display save and cancel buttons, and put focus on the first input field. I can accomplish this myself when I hardcode all the ID's I need. But that really isn't going to work for my situation.

The only unique identifier between each form is the form tag's ID.

What I'm trying to do is when the page loads, I want to add an ID to the edit link and also append the forms ID to that newly created ID for the edit link.

Here is a very basic code example to show what I'm working with:

```
<form id="form-1">
  <a class="edit">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
<form id="form-2">
  <a class="edit">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
<form id="form-3">
  <a class="edit">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
```

I'm looking to dynamically add an ID to each edit link, without having to explicitly set in the html. I want to add an ID of "edit-[form ID]", with [form ID] being the ID that of the form.

So after the page loads I want the forms to look like this:

```
<form id="form-1">
  <a class="edit" id="edit-form-1">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
<form id="form-2">
  <a class="edit" id="edit-form-2">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
<form id="form-3">
  <a class="edit" id="edit-form-3">Edit</a>
  ...
</form>
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but can't get it to work properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").each( function(index) {
            var formID = $("form").attr("id");
            $(".edit").attr("id", "edit-" + formID );
        });
});
```

Unfortunately, it is adding `id="edit-form-1"` to all the form edit links.

There are other elements in the form I need to do something similar with, but seeing one working example should help me with the rest.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The real question is why do you need these ID's? If you want event handlers, you can just do `$(this).closest('form')` to access each form related to the button that was clicked, you don't need ID's?

Comment: You know, you may be right. I wanted to add ID's to certain things in order to use as selectors for click events. I"m not very experienced with JS, so probably aren't approaching this the best way. However, I'm kind of on a tight time schedule, so just trying get it to work. I still get confused with the "this" selector if I'm not using it as it is shown in the examples on jQuery's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.id` and the `.edit` child of `this`

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(".edit", this).attr("id", "edit-" + this.id);
});
```

where `$(".edit", this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find(".edit")`

I must admit that it's a bit strange you need to add those ID... You can always do something like:

```
$(".edit").on("click", function() {

    var $myForm = $(this).closest("form");
    // Do something with $myForm

});
```

without ever carrying about form or button ID

Comment: Hey Roko, 

Thanks for the help and explanation. So if I were to use your recommended script, where is says // Do something with $myForm, how would I then target certain classes. 

For example, I have some form fields that are disabled by default, using the disabled property. I have a class on those called "disabled". I need to target those inputs with the disabled class, then remove the disabled property. 

So would somehow need to incorporate something like this:

    $(".disabled")removeProp("disabled");

Comment: @JonathanRyanPatterson simply like `$myForm.find(".disabled").something()`

Answer (score 0):

So based off of Roko's answer, I was able to achieve what I was looking for by doing this:

```
$(".edit).on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("form").find(".disabled").removeProp("disabled");
});
```

However, I was not able to get it to work when saving to a variable then using the variable $myForm. But I probably wasn't using it correctly.

Thanks again for your guy's help!